# Nuxt2 SSR throws error require() of ES Module

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

While I change my Nuxt2 application with Axios for API Calls, the error is as follows. The application is running in `ssr:true` mode.

```
require() of ES Module \frontend\node_modules\axios\index.js
from \frontend\node_modules\vue-server-renderer\build.dev.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in
\frontend\node_modules\vue-server-renderer\build.dev.js to a dynamic import()
which is available in all CommonJS modules.
```

Thanks in advance!